# Syntax error in debug mode

Tags: bugs, syntax, piecewise

**Bug introduced in 8.0 and persisting through 10.3.0**

---

It appears that in debug mode, the `\[Piecewise]` symbol and its associated grid give a syntax error. For a minimal reproduction, enable the debugger, and type in the front end:

<kbd>Esc</kbd> pw <kbd>Esc</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Return</kbd>)

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Note that the grid must be typed using the keyboard. Inserting it using the menu does not trigger the bug.

[image: Screenshot]

Is it a bug? Are there ways to fix that except write it in the input form?

Comment: I get the same error message on Win 64-bit 10.0.1.

Comment: Still there in M10.1.0.

Comment: It was introduced in version 8. I never use the 2-d input, but I did in this case, and could not reproduce your observations at first. The problem actually comes from the grid and not from the piecewise bracket itself. I didn't observe the problem on the first attempt because I used the menu to insert the grid (not remembering its keystroke, as I don't use this normally). Only when I used Ctrl-Enter to insert the grid did I see the problem.